# Populating a array of date tuples

Tags: scala

i am trying to pass a list of date ranges needs to be in the below format.

```scala
val predicates =
Array(
“2021-05-16” → “2021-05-17”,
“2021-05-18” → “2021-05-19”,
“2021-05-20” → “2021-05-21”)
```

I am then using map to create a range of conditions that will be passed to the jdbc method.

```scala
val predicates =
  Array(
    “2021-05-16” → “2021-05-17”,
    “2021-05-18” → “2021-05-19”,
    “2021-05-20” → “2021-05-21”
  ).map { case (start, end) =>
    s"cast(NEW_DT as date) >= date ‘$start’ AND cast(NEW_DT as date) <= date ‘$end’"
  }
```

The process will need to run daily and i need to dynamically populate these values as i cannot use the hard coded way.

Need help in how i can return these values from a method with incrementing start_date and end_date tuples that can generate like above.I had a mere idea like below but as i am new to scala not able to figure out. Please help

```scala
def predicateRange(start_date: String, end_date: String): Array[(String,String)] = {
  // iterate over the date values and add + 1 to both start and end and return the tuple
}
```

Comment: You mean your `predicates` array should update each day?

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that every range is the same duration, and that each date range starts the next day after the end of the previous range.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def dateRanges(start: String
              ,rangeLen: Int
              ,ranges: Int): Array[(String,String)] = {
  val startDate =
    LocalDate.parse(start, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
  Array.iterate(startDate -> startDate.plusDays(rangeLen), ranges){
    case (_, end) => end.plusDays(1) -> end.plusDays(rangeLen+1)
  }.map{case (s,e) => (s.toString, e.toString)}
}
```

usage:

```
dateRanges("2021-05-16", 1, 3)
//res0: Array[(String, String)] = Array((2021-05-16,2021-05-17), (2021-05-18,2021-05-19), (2021-05-20,2021-05-21))
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs ,got this implemented and works  nicely,Can you please clarify what exatly happens here  // case (_, end) => end.plusDays(1) -> end.plusDays(rangeLen+1)
  }.map{case (s,e) => (s.toString, e.toString)}

Comment: Each successive `(LocalDate,LocalDate)` tuple is built from the previous, but we're only interested in end-date of the previous tuple: `case (_,end) =>` Build the new date range by adding to that date: `end.plusDays(...` After all the dates have been built change them to strings: `.map(...`

Comment: We can avoid that extra map by using `Array.tabulate`.

Comment: @sarveshseri; Indeed. [Proof of concept.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zlMma3VdTOayOLaR1y4cCQ)

Answer (score 3):

You can use following method to generate your tuple array,

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def generateArray3(startDateString: String, endDateString: String): Array[(String, String)] = {
  val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
  val startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateString)
  val endDate = LocalDate.parse(endDateString)

  val daysCount = startDate.until(endDate).getDays

  val dateStringTuples = Array.tabulate(daysCount)(i => {
    val firstDate = startDate.plusDays(i)
    val secondDate = startDate.plusDays(i + 1)
    (dateFormatter.format(firstDate), dateFormatter.format(secondDate))
  })

  dateStringTuples
}
```

Usage:

```scala
println("--------------------------")
generateArray("2021-02-27", "2021-03-02").foreach(println)
println("--------------------------")
generateArray("2021-05-27", "2021-06-02").foreach(println)
println("--------------------------")
generateArray("2021-12-27", "2022-01-02").foreach(println)
println("--------------------------")
```

output :

```
--------------------------
(2021-02-27,2021-02-28)
(2021-02-28,2021-03-01)
(2021-03-01,2021-03-02)
--------------------------
(2021-05-27,2021-05-28)
(2021-05-28,2021-05-29)
(2021-05-29,2021-05-30)
(2021-05-30,2021-05-31)
(2021-05-31,2021-06-01)
(2021-06-01,2021-06-02)
--------------------------
(2021-12-27,2021-12-28)
(2021-12-28,2021-12-29)
(2021-12-29,2021-12-30)
(2021-12-30,2021-12-31)
(2021-12-31,2022-01-01)
(2022-01-01,2022-01-02)
--------------------------
```